# Simple messaging in Google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, messaging

I try to write simple plugin for chrome, and i have content script and extension itself. I try to setup simple messaging, according google docs:
[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple)

Here is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Plugin",
  "description": "My Plugin",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is `content.js` file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      debugger;
      if (request.action === "GetPageContent") {
          sendResponse({ dom: document.documentElement.outerHTML });
      }
  }
);
```

And here is snippet code from `app.js` thats send message to content script file:

```
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "GetPageContent" }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

So, when i click button to trigger execution, it fails in `content.js`file
on line `sendResponse({ dom: document.documentElement.outerHTML });`

Saying that:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener
 Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage:
 Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
```

What does it mean? I'am not using any port, also in google docs there is also no any mention about ports for simple messaging.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a cause, the chrome developer console, if it opens alongside when i am test my extension, then this error occurs.